# Почему дух перестал создавать пустые описания?

Tags: обсуждение, дух-сообщества, описание-метки

Вчера перетаскивал описания метки [mint](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mint) в [linux-mint](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-mint) и заметил интересную особенность:
В старой истории [есть пустые версии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/433693/revisions) от Духа, а [в новой нет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/587230/revisions). Почему так?

Comment: Эволюция Духа :) А вообще, метка `linux-mint` получается имела ревизию 1, созданную Духом, а теперь эта ревизия пропала?

Answer (score 3):

## Угадайка!*

Вообще пустая ревизия от ненастоящего пользователя похожа на костылик с целью подстроиться под существующие ограничения в системе. И у меня есть подозрение, к каким именно ограничениям.

Скорее всего, дело в том, что:

- **в первом случае имела место предлагаемая правка**. Но это правка, и она должна **править** уже существующую ревизию ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/587663/revisions)).
- **во втором случае описание было создано без утверждения сообществом**.

---

<sup>***Т. е. это не достоверные сведения, а моя догадка.**</sup>

Comment: Точно, так это и происходит. Добавил пруф.

Comment: @NickVolynkin дык в вопросе ж такой пруф вроде уже есть :)

Comment: Там старая метка, можно подумать что просто логика сайта поменялась за год. А тут вчерашняя.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ах, это. Ну, это опровергает теорию об эволюции Духа, да.